# How to import Google Maps API into PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, database, postgresql, google-maps, curl

I am trying to transfer data from a JSON file produced by the **Google Maps API** onto my **PostgreSQL** database. This is done through **cURL** and I made sure that the permissions have been correctly set.

*The url:*

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=London&destinations=Paris&key=AIza-[key-redacted]-3z6ho-o

*The query:*

```
copy bookings.import(info) from program 'C:/temp/mycurl/curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=London&destinations=Paris&key=AIzaSyBIhOMI68hTIFarH4jrb_eKUmvY3z6ho-o" --insecure'
```

However, when I try to do this on my table with column 'info' of type 'json', I get the following error:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL:  The input string
>   ended unexpectedly. CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: { COPY import, line
>   1, column info: "{"
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json SQL state: 22P02 Detail: The
>   input string ended unexpectedly. Context: JSON data, line 1: { COPY
>   import, line 1, column info: "{"

I am trying to not include things such as PHP or any other tool currently, yet if the only option is that I would certainly consider it.

What exactly do you guys think I am doing wrong? Is it the syntax, the format or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: The maps API is pretty-printing the output and it looks like the COPY is choking on the whitespace. `COPY` assumes that each line is a new record.

Comment: would that be a problem with the API or with the COPY? thanks!

Comment: Warning: You have put your un-redacted key in the example.

Answer (score 0):

COPY assumes that each newline indicates a new record. Unfortunately, the Google Maps DistanceMatrix API is pretty-printing your response which means that it comes through as 23 rows, none of which are valid JSON.

You can get around this by piping the `curl` response through something like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

`copy imports(info) from program 'curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=London&destinations=Paris&key=<my_key>" --insecure | /usr/local/bin/jq "." -c'`

`jq` has lots of useful features if you want to massage the response a bit more before stashing it in the database.

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri!!! It worked like a charm, all saved beautifully in one row!!

For anyone interested, here is the code for it; 
copy bookings.import(info) from program 'C:\temp\mycurl\curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=London&destinations=Paris&key=[key-redacted]" --insecure | C:\temp\mycurl\jq "." -c'